# Box API: read user (by id)

Tags: java, box-api

is there an API to get user by id?
I mean the internal Box id.
For example, if I create this user:

```
User: test_8cb44f10-beb8-4992-9101-d41a42b4a84f
Hostname: null
Login: test_8cb44f10-beb8-4992-9101-d41a42b4a84f@test.com
ID: 2539778125
```

Can I search by `ID: 2539778125`?
And what is its counterpart in Java SDK?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I misunderstand your question, you should be using [https://api.box.com/2.0/users/user_id](https://developer.box.com/v2.0/reference#users).

Comment: Yes, and thanks. But I was looking for the Java SDK utility that calls this API. I'm developing using that SDK.

Answer (score 0):

In Java SDK it should be:

```
 private BoxDeveloperEditionAPIConnection api;
 // ... init api
 String id = "0";
 new BoxUser(api, id).getInfo();
```